# Private Temporary Storage Directory in Laravel

Tags: laravel

With Laravel, I assume that the `storage/` folder is a good place to unzip some temporary files into. So in the code, I mentioned this path: `storage/tempdir`. Like the following:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($request->excelFile->path());
$dir = "storage/tempdir";
$zip->extractTo($dir);
```

But the unzipped files end up in `public/storage/tempdir/`

This way they are accessible for public, and I don't want that.

How can I refer to `storage/tempdir` on both my Windows and Linux machines? tnx.

Comment: Show the code, please.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin did so

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`storage_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-storage-path) helper:

```php
$zip->extractTo(storage_path('tempdir'));
```

Comment: this will not work properly when there are multiple concurrent extractions

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/spatie/temporary-directory

This package offers a better solution as it allows **multiple concurrent** extractions without their files being mixed into the same fixed folder of `storage_path('tempdir')`

Using a fixed folder may work for simple cases, but once scaled up, the issues it creates are hard to troubleshoot and debug.

Answer (score 0):

The `extractTo` function would always create a folder in the `storage/public` directory.

I used William's suggestion but had to prepend the `app/` folder to the directory and that did the trick. For this example it would be something like this;

```php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($request->excelFile->path());

$dir = "storage/tempdir";

if (!Storage::disk('local')->exists($dir)) {
    Storage::makeDirectory($dir);
}

$this->zip->extractTo(storage_path('app/' . $dir));
$this->zip->close();
```

I haven't tested it with multiple concurrent extractions.

Laravel 10.x.